# Need help identifying this scale

Tags: scales, transcription

Yesterday my friend sent me a recording of a song. I was particularly stunned and interested in a scale (maybe not a scale, but it does sound like one.) I decided to upload the scale here: https://soundcloud.com/kris-pianist/scale. Trying my best, I cannot transcribe it. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Drop the sound file into Audacity, calculate the FFT for each note,  and you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, basically both hands play an Abmin(maj9) arpeggio, the right in 16ths while the left in 8ths.
Here is the transcription fot it:

[image]

Talking about scales, from this excerpt it can be either an Ab melodic minor or an Ab harmonic minor scale.

Comment: OK, so how did you generate this transcription?

Comment: Piano + Ears :D The score is written with Sibelius 7.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a scale, it's a five-note-arpeggio. It is an Abminmaj9 ('A flat minor major nine') arpeggio. This chord has the notes

`Ab Cb Eb G Bb`

And on the recording it is played like this (from high to low):

`Bb Ab G Eb Cb` (and continued like this through 3 lower octaves)

The last note of the arpeggio (Cb, after descending 3 octaves) resolves to Bb, which is the root of the next chord (Bb major).

Comment: An arpeggio is done over a scale, so it is a scale indeed :)

Comment: @m0skit0: Forgive me, but your comment doesn't make a lot of sense :)